# Regex with \n and \s within group not showing expected match

Tags: regex

I have the below regex:

```
/interface\s\w+\d(\/\d+)+(\n\s([\w\d\.\-]+\s?)+)+/
```

Why is it only matching the top two lines of the below, and not the rest of the commands??

```
interface FastEthernet0/2
 description Lab
 switchport access vlan 88
 switchport mode access
 switchport block multicast
 switchport block unicast
 switchport port-security
 srr-queue bandwidth limit 60
!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not matching the rest of the commands because in the repeating group `(\n\s([\w\d\.\-]+\s?)+` you are matching an optional whitespace char `\s?` which will match until `description` and the following whitespace char. Then the inner group will repeat and matches `Lab` and the `\s?` will match the newline.

The group tries to repeat again, only this time `[\w\.\-]+` can not match. The outer group now tries to match a newline from `\n\s` but that is already matched by the previous `\s` so the match stops.

What you might do (and if you don't need the capturing groups make them non capturing `(?:`) is to repeat a space followed by the character class `(?: [\w.-]+)*` to match until the end of the string.

Then that will be repeated again giving you all the lines except the one that starts   with `!`

For example:

```
interface\s\w+\d(?:\/\d+)+(?:\n\s+(?:[\w.-]+(?: [\w.-]+)*)+)+
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccbw9z/1)

Note that `\w` also matches `\d` and you don't have to escape the dot and the hyphen at the end in the character class which could the shortened to `[\w.-]+`

A bit more efficient solution could be to start the match with the interface part and then match all the following lines that do not start with a lines that only contains `!`

```
interface\s\w+\d(?:\/\d+)+(?:\n(?!!$).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoANov/1)

Comment: If you compare your demo with mine, your solution could be better. It will depend on what OP wants.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Hi there, when you say my solution could be better can you note which part so I can impove?

Comment: Ok thanks.  What about preventing a match where there is a blank line in between commands?  And what if I require the `!` at the end?

Comment: @kuhnflyfish 1 option is to use a positive lookahead if the comma should be there but not matched. See https://regex101.com/r/zkjvAh/4 Or using a capturing group. See https://regex101.com/r/zkjvAh/5 If the `!` Should be there, then use https://regex101.com/r/zkjvAh/3

Comment: Your regex matches the whole content in one group, mine does it in more than one group. I think one group is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you break a line between the 3rd and 4th line, or between the 5th and 6th, and so on, the next line after the break line will be matched. It is because of this:

```
interface\s\w+\d(\/\d+)+(\n\s([\w\d\.\-]+\s?)+)+
-------------------------^
```

That `\n` is requiring to have a break line to match the others, so if you change it to `\n*` it will work by not requiring a new line anymore:

```
interface\s\w+\d(\/\d+)+(\n*\s([\w\d\.\-]+\s?)+)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z2kv5s/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might be desired output here, maybe we could just apply a simple expression in `s` mode, for instance:

```
(interface.*)[!]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA76Ge/1)